# Exception : java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Buenos días Comunidad:

Tengo un archivo employee.dat con el siguiente contenido (la numeración correlativa en el margen izquierdo no es parte del contenido del archivo):

1. empleados:3
2. Carl Hacker | IT Manager | 75000.0 | 1987 | 10 | 15
3. Harry Cracker | IT Analyst | 50000.0 | 1989 | 8 | 1
4. Tony Tester | Software Developer | 40000.0 | 1990 | 1 | 15 
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecuta obtengo la exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "r"

El error lo marca en otro método que hace la lectura del archivo y construye los objetos employee (Exactamente en la linea: double salary = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);

```
public static Employee readEmployee(Scanner in)
    {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\ |");
            String name = tokens[0];
            String role = tokens[1];
            double salary = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
            int day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);
            return new Employee(name, role, salary, year, month, day);
    }
```

El método main desde el cual hago la llamada es:

```
// recupera todos los registros en un nuevo array
    try(Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("employee.dat"), "UTF-8"))
    {
        Employee[] newStaff = Employee.readData(in);
        // print los nuevos registro de empleados
        for(Employee e : newStaff)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Espero su amable ayuda con esta excepción.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es la forma cómo estás dividiendo los tokens:

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\\ |");
```

Si tu intención es que el split ocurra con la cadena siguiente: `" | "`, entonces, el split debe expresarse de la forma siguiente:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" \\| "); // no te olvides el espacio al principio y al final
```

La barra vertical tiene significado especial en regex, por eso debes colocar el `\\` en frente para que se interprete de forma literal.

Comment: De paso, de ser posible, sería considerado de tu parte que modificaras tu pregunta para que refleje el problema original que tuvistes además del nuevo, ya que en realidad @Error404 sí resolvió tu problema original. Es solo que aún tenías otro problema que necesitaba atención. Con eso en mente, yo marcaría su respuesta como aceptada (haz click on el "check" a la izquierda de su respuesta).

Comment: Buen apunte el añadir el espacio al principio y al final. Sin embargo, utilizando `Double.parseDouble()` no sería del todo necesario ya que mediante este método traduces el String a Double (si puede hacerlo). Si tiene espacios no los detecta como String y te traduce el Double sin problemas.

Comment: @Error404: No sabía que `Double.parseDouble()` manejaba los espacios de esa manera. Me parece un poco raro, pero tienes toda la razón. Sin embargo, `Integer.parseInt()` definitivamente no maneja los espacios automáticamente, de modo que para evitar un error en la línea que sigue, hay que quitarlos antes de hacer el parse.

Comment: Yo la verdad que es algo que descubrí hace tiempo pero nunca he llegado a conseguir documentación oficial sobre ello. Supongo que los números enteros "siempre son más raritos" jeje

Answer (score 2):

Como dice la documentación de [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) este error se produce debido a que estás intentando recuperar un dato que no se corresponde con el tipo de dato que existe en el fichero.

Sospecho que es porque en tu fichero en tu primera línea tienes lo siguiente:

```
numero de empleados:3
```

lo que significa que no es simplemente un entero, si no que el número es parte de un string y tu lo estás intentando recuperar como entero.

Yo te recomiendo que leas la línea entera como un String y luego dividas el String tomando como referencia los dos puntos (:). Te creará un array con dos posiciones, el texto anterior a los dos puntos y el texto posterior a los dos puntos. Tendrás que coger el texto posterior a los dos puntos para recuperar el número de empleados.

Por último, pasar dicho String a entero (parsear). Algo similar a esto:

```
String todaLaLinea = in.nextLine(); //Recuperamos la línea "numero de empleados:3"
String lineaDividida[] = todaLaLinea.split(":"); //Dividimos la línea y la almacenamos en un array de Strings tomando como referencia los dos puntos
int numeroEmpleados = Integer.parseInt(lineaDividida[1]); //Parseamos el número de empleados de String a int
```

**EDIT**: Para que la respuesta no se quede desactualizada con la nueva edición de tu pregunta (ya que has quitado el código y error de la pregunta original), como ha comentado `@sstan`, el nuevo problema que tienes es a la hora de hacer el split.

Cuando haces un split tienes que escapar los caracteres especiales, es decir, tienes que tratarlos como un String y no como un carácter especial. Para ello, como bien has hecho, necesitas usar la doble barra invertida `\\` justo antes del carácter especial. El problema es que para tu caso has dejado un espacio entre la doble barra invertida y el carácter especial:

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\\ |");
```

por lo que tendría que ser así:

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
```

En tu caso, tienes un espacio antes y después del carácter especial, por lo que tendrías que tratarlo también a la hora de hacer el split:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" \\| ");
```

**Como curiosidad:** Si todos los números fueran `Double`, podrías usar sin ningún problema `String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");` porque no parece que los espacios le importen y te va a devolver el valor `Double` sin ningún problema. Sin embargo, como en este caso tienes también enteros, la función `Integer.parseInt()` te dará un `java.lang.NumberFormatException` si no detectas los espacios.

Comment: yo no pondria `.substring(todaLaLinea.length() - 1); `porque el numero de empleado puede ser mayor a 1 digito. puedes hacer `split(":")[1]`

Comment: ahora, todaLinea es de tipo String, pero recibe un in.nextInt()??

Comment: @DavidLeandroHeinzeMüller ostias es verdad hahha

Comment: Intente en lugar de decir en el archivo: Numero de empleados: 3, Que solo diga 3 como primera línea y mantuve la línea

Comment: mantuve la línea: int n = in.nextInt(); Ahora me da la exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "r"   :((

Comment: @lois6b Tienes toda la razón, ya está corregido.

Comment: @DavidLeandroHeinzeMüller Tienes toda la razón, quería poner nextLine en vez de nextInt(). Lo siento, ya he corregido el código (con la recomendación de lois6b).

Comment: La verdad estoy con ganas de romper todo, no sé cual es el probema, haciendo los cambios me da el error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "r". Y cuando coloco [0] me arroja la palabra numero.

Comment: @DavidLeandroHeinzeMüller Por favor, edita la pregunta con el código que tienes actualmente y el contenido del fichero actual. Esta respuesta funcionará cuando tengas "numero de empleados: tu numero de empleados" como primera linea del fichero.

Comment: @DavidLeandroHeinzeMüller Y no te desesperes, al principio es complicado pero una vez que le coges el truco, la programación es muy divertida :)

Comment: No dudo que la programación sea divertida. Lo que si dudo es si ¿Java, es un leguaje de programación divertido? Pero, hay que continuar. :)

Comment: @DavidLeandroHeinzeMüller Yo personalmente al principio estuve a punto de abrirme la cabeza por algún punto y coma que se me olvidaba pero ahora es el lenguaje que más me gusta. Por favor, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha resuelto tu error. Gracias!

Comment: Acabo de editar el código, aún no logro superar el error. Gracias a todos por su ayuda y tiempo :)

Comment: @DavidLeandroHeinzeMüller Acabo de ver tu edición. He actualizado la respuesta para que no se quede desactualizada pero te pediría que pusieras la pregunta entera con el código inicial y el error inicial que te daba. Si no, tal y como ha comentado sstan, la primera parte de la respuesta queda totalmente desactualizada.